# In functional programming, is "saving the state" of an algorithm at the recursive function argument cheating?

Tags: functional-programming

for instance, lets suppose we had to write an algorithm to get the max value of an array of integers, could we still call the code functional if we make the recursive function return various information that simulates an assignment to a global object? an exemple:

```
function getMax(array, props={}) {
    const {index = 0, actualMax = array[0]}= props ///initial props
    const arrayNotEnded = array[index + 1] !== undefined
    if (arrayNotEnded) {
        const maxOf= (a, b) => a > b ? a : b
        const newMax = maxOf(actualMax, array[index+1])
        const nextIndex = index+1
        return getMax(array, {index:nextIndex, actualMax:newMax} )
    }else return actualMax
}
```

a funny thing about that is, in Haskell, we cannot have optional arguments, so this logic would not be something cool to work with, since we would have to pass the initial props every time we would need to call this function.

Comment: Haskell would probably use nested functions for that, such as `getMax arr = innerMax 0 (head arr) where innerMax arr index actualMax = ...`. It doesn't mutate state and it gives the same answers for every call, so I'd call it functional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you could consider it cheating, but this is a well-known technique in functional programming, the *accumulator* argument [[1]](https://wiki.haskell.org/Performance/Accumulating_parameter)[[2]](https://web.cs.wpi.edu/%7Ecs1101/common/accumulator.html)[[3]](https://101wiki.softlang.org/Concept:Accumulator_parameter). Remember: code doesn't become functional by not having state, functional programming is all about *making state explicit*. There's no better way of doing that than by making it a parameter of your function.

Your code has some other problems, though. Most prominently, the state should be internal to your function, only being passed to a helper function (that might be locally declared or separate) but not as part of your function's public interface. This also prevents confusing your helper function by passing invalid state (e.g. out-of-bound indices). And yes, also the optional parameter smells - not because you think this is not possible in Haskell (it is, using `Maybe`), but because it can be forgotten or passed mistakenly. Instead, the helper function should have a required state parameter, and `getMax` should have none.
Last but not least, you should avoid out-of-bounds indexed access on arrays - check the length to know where the end is, don't compare to `undefined`. This includes unconditionally accessing `array[0]` - that makes it very easy to overlook that your function can return `undefined`. Make this error condition explicit as well.

Here's how I'd write it:

```
function getMax(array) {
    if (!array.length)
        throw new Error("array must be non-empty");
    else
        return maxFrom(1, array[0]);

    function maxFrom(index, max) {
        if (index < array.length)
            return maxFrom(index+1, array[index] > max ? array[index] : max);
        else
            return actualMax
    }
}
```

Even better than throwing exceptions would be if you'd had an algebraic data type at hand that you could return to represent the error-or-result.

Comment: Just a doubt: 
When you say about the Maybe in Haskell to do optional parameters, are you saying about allow an argument to be the "Nothing"? Are you sure this could be considered an optional parameter? Because we need to specify that we want that parameter to be Nothing, unlike other languages like javascript that we can simply call the function without it.

Comment: @Vitorfigm Yes, it's semantically equivalent, like passing `undefined` in JavaScript. That you can omit the `undefined` argument in JS is just a syntactical feature. And of course there are other solutions as well in Haskell, from using a record parameter whose defaults you can overwrite or not, to advanced overloading trickery that actually allow variadic (omittable) arguments.